# Jenkins: Deployment of war file to Wildfly fails

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, deployment, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to deploy a war-file to a wildfly server as a job in a jenkins server. The jenkins-application/server itself is a war-file which is deployed on the same wildfly-server.

I managed to automate the maven build so far.

For the deployment I use the WildFly Deployer Plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WildFly+Deployer+Plugin

I'm using WildFly 9.0.2 Final.

Jenkins version is: 2.7.4.

this is the configuration im using:

[image]

I'm getting this error in the console output:

```
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\laudatio\.jenkins\workspace\game-of-life-packaging\target\jsfapplication.war to C:\Users\laudatio\.m2\repository\com\java\ee\jsf\1.0\jsf-1.0.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\laudatio\.jenkins\workspace\game-of-life-packaging\pom.xml to C:\Users\laudatio\.m2\repository\com\java\ee\jsf\1.0\jsf-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.638 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-08T22:24:41+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/196M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\laudatio\.jenkins\workspace\game-of-life-packaging\pom.xml to com.java.ee/jsf/1.0/jsf-1.0.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\laudatio\.jenkins\workspace\game-of-life-packaging\target\jsfapplication.war to com.java.ee/jsf/1.0/jsf-1.0.war
channel stopped
FATAL: Unable to initialize command context.
Build step 'Deploy WAR/EAR to WildFly' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that this is related to the following bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33504 ?